# Which commandline tool (called "...edit" or so) manages virtual machines (Hyper-V or VM-ware or so)

Tags: command-line, virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v

I would like to add a virtual machine to my VM-Ware, but this caused some issues (something about some "##_##" feature, like "CF_DC" or something).

According to a website, I needed to use some commandline tool (called <something_edit>) and alter a configuration entry with a large name from "Auto" to "Off"), which I did.

But after having done that, whenever I start up my virtual machine on VM-Ware, I get the "blue screen of death".

I would like to put that commandline configuration setting back to "Auto", but I don't know the name anymore (I never expected a blue screen of death to appear and restart my entire PC).

Does anybody know the name of that commandline tool, so that I can put it back?
It was something like:

```
Prompt> ...edit /...
... (about 10-15 configuration entries)
Hyper<some long name>    Auto
...
```

**Edit:**
My answer mentions what NOT to do in case of the mentioned `CG_DG` problem. Does anybody know what can be done in order to solve that issue?

**Edit: thoughts about root cause:**
The original problem is about two features not being compatible (the one from the main computer and the one from the virtual computer). If both computers are Windows-10, how can they have incompatible features?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem: I had added a Windows-10 virtual machine to my VM-Ware configuration, and when starting it up, I got following error message:

```
Windows_10 - VMware Workstation 15 Player
---------------------------
VMware Player and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible.  
VMware Player can be run after disabling Device/Credential Guard.  
Please visit http://www.vmware.com/go/turnoff_CG_DG for more details.
---------------------------
OK
```

Screenshot:
[image]

The website, mentioned in the error message, proposes this "solution":

```
bcdedit /enum
```

This lists a bunch of boot parameters, one of them being:

```
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

There was the proposal to put this value to `Off`, but doing that causes the blue screen of death, every time a virtual machine is started up (As I have a docker desktop in my startup folder, you can imagine the time I lost figuring this one out :-) ).

So:
**NEVER** set `hypervisorlaunchtype` to `Off` using `bcdedit` unless you know **200%** sure what you are doing :-)